# Saving Images in Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on `Worklight Developer Edition Version 6.1`. I have created a native component inside a Hybrid app. I am using `WL.NativePage.show` method for navigating from HTML to native pages. I am having 5 images in an array in a native page. I need to save those images in a DB and need to access the same in a HTML page.

1. Can anyone tell me, how to do this using DB? (should be common for both Native and Web app)
2. Can I use Worklight JSONStore in Developer Edition ?

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 6.1 does **not** support `JSONStore` in native pages.

Possible solution:

What you can do instead is save the images locally using native code.
Then, in order to access these locally-saved images via the web portion of the app, you could write a custom Cordova plug-in to access it.

You will need to consult with the iOS SDK documentation regarding how to save the file locally.
Some resources:

- [Download an Image and Save it as PNG or JPEG in iPhone SDK](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/)
- [Adding native functionality using Cordova plug-ins](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)